# Call Custom SQL Function with entityframework dynamic queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dynamic

I am using `System.Linq.Dynamic` to support dynamic query building. I need to call custom SQL function inside the OrderBy/Where strings.

I was able to achieve above requirement in the static Link To Entities through introducing the SQL function to my `DBContext` using `DbFunction`. however this is not working with dynamic queries.

Below is sample for the working static linq followed by not working dynamic linq, TestDBContext.GetText is Sql Function takes two strings and returns string.

```
var query = from user in TestDBContext.User
  join address in TestDBContext.Address on user.Id equals address.UserId
  orderby TestDBContext.GetText(address.Country, "1")
  select address;
```

now, I need to do same on dynamic Linq

```
var query = from user in TestDBContext.User
    join address in TestDBContext.Address on user.Id equals address.UserId
    select address;

    query = query.OrderBy("TestDBContext.GetText(address.Country, '1') ASC");
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this using `System.Linq.Dynamic`? Or another package? Any ideas might help.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the static usage?

Comment: Hi Ivan, sample for static linq has been added to the to query.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't make it work, looks like is unsupported. Tried passing the db context like `.OrderBy("@0.GetText(address.Country, '1') ASC", TestDBContext)` but no luck - they check for a predefined types.

Comment: Try using intermediate static projection like `var query = from ... join ... select new { address, countryText = TestDBContext.GetText(address.Country, "1") }; var dynamicQuery = query.OrderBy("countryText ASC").Select("country"); `

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan, the workaround you suggest is working :). Thanks again.